# Integer calculations on GPU

Tags: performance, optimization, integer, gpgpu

For my work it's particularly interesting to do integer calculations, which obviously are not what GPUs were made for. My question is: Do modern GPUs support efficient integer operations? I realize this should be easy to figure out for myself, but I find conflicting answers (for example [yes](http://www.golubev.com/about_cpu_and_gpu_2_en.htm) vs [no](http://www.gpgpu.org/w/index.php/FAQ#Which_number_formats_do_GPUs_provide.3F)), so I thought it best to ask.

Also, are there any libraries/techniques for arbitrary precision integers on GPUs?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, you need to consider the hardware you're using: GPU devices performance widely differs from a constructor to another.
Second, it also depends on the operations considered: for example adds might be faster than multiplies.

In my case, I'm only using NVIDIA devices. For this kind of hardware: the [official documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#arithmetic-instructions__throughput-native-arithmetic-instructions) announces equivalent performance for both 32-bit integers and 32-bit single precision floats with the new architecture (Fermi). Previous architecture (Tesla) used to offer equivalent performance for 32-bit integers and floats but only when considering adds and logical operations.

But once again, this may not be true depending on the device and instructions you use.

Comment: I think one thing to note is, that yes almost for all architectures all CUDA Cores on a GPU can be used for integer operations, but there is no fused multiply add for integers, so that the peak integer operations per second is only half the peak FLOPs.